# google maps api mobile rendering

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-maps

I am trying to open up a SIMPLE MAP on my website on a mobile iOS device but am getting the google map completely distorted.  The code is straight from the google maps api documentation.

[image: iOS Device Capture]

I do use a content delivery system to help enhance speed, but have disables all cache without any luck. Is this a local issues or is something else going on with mobile devices??

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- This stylesheet contains specific styles for displaying the map
         on this page. Replace it with your own styles as described in the
         documentation:
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/maps/documentation/javascript/demos/demos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=''&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool issue, I experienced this last year when I loaded google maps over `http` instead of `https` (unsupported, but still worked, until it didn't). It's likely a caching issue. Can you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle? Unfixable unless you can reproduce it.

Comment: If google maps base tiles are sent with the wrong cache headers (rare, but it's not unheard of) sometimes local ISPs end up holding on to improper tiles resulting in what you see.